# Need help in BEAST attack prevention for DV SSL

Tags: apache, security, ssl, https, tls1.2

I recently purchased the SSL from SSL 123 DV Thawte Inc for one of my client's domain. Post installation of the certificate I checked the domain using crypto-checker provided by Thawte.

I received an alert stating the site is open to BEAST Attack vulnerability.

To dig deeper, I used SSLLabs to identify the Insecure Ciphers.

Following are the Ciphers identified as not secured. I need help in closing these holes.

Screenshot of in secured ciphers

[image: Screenshot of insecured ciphers]

I am using Apache 2.4 web server over Ubuntu 16 64 Bit.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability with latest openssl 1.1.0c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/330837/56041) on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Any up to date browser has circumventions for BEAST, meanwhile  I don't think those ciphers are flagged because of BEAST in the SSL Labs report.  It turns out the BEAST alternatives needed for
a high level of compat (rc4) are worse then the previously BEAST-affected ciphers.

You should use an alternate SSLCipherSuite to make sure weak ciphers are at the bottom instead of that one you have at the top. Instead of trying to ad-lib it, you should start with a config from https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

Comment: Also see [POODLE attacks on SSLv3](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html), [Chrome and the BEAST](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/09/23/chromeandbeast.html), [BEAST followup](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/01/15/beastfollowup.html) and [Living with HTTPS](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/07/19/hope9talk.html).